# Sql Update CPT from publish to draft and particular custom field

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-field, mysql, post-status

I have:

CPT: match
custom field: played

Is it possible by MySql to change the status from publish to draft of all posts of CPT 'match' with custom field set as '0'?

A good start can be

> UPDATE
>    wp_posts
>   SET
>    post_status = 'draft'
>   WHERE
>    post_type = 'match'
>    AND meta_key = 'played'
>    AND meta_value = 0;

but `meta_key` and `meta_value` are not in `wp_posts` table.

Thanks a lot for your support

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to use JOIN to achieve this:

```
UPDATE wp_posts p INNER JOIN wp_postmeta pm ON p.ID = pm.post_id 
SET p.post_status = 'draft'
WHERE p.post_type = 'match' AND pm.meta_key = 'played' AND pm.meta_value = 0;
```